# Private setter vs Backing Property in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm an old Java fan and trying to understand Kotlin basics. Can someone tell me what is the difference between these codes:

```
private val _users = mutableListOf<User>()
val users: List<User>
get() = _users
```

VS

```
var _users: mutableListOf<User>()
private set
```

As far as understand, upper code provides set _users only in that class and get it publicly which seems pretty same with the code below but in Google docs they say it's backing property which i don't get what it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both examples are really totally different. You need to understand the difference between:

- val MutableList

and:

- var List

First makes possible to modify the contents of a list, but you can't replace the list object itself. Second, you can replace the list object, but you cannot modify its contents. This isn't really specific to Kotlin, it is the same in Java. `val` (or making a setter private) is like `final` field and `List` is like wrapping a list with `Collections.unmodifiableList()` - they're different things.

In your first example, neither the external nor internal code can replace the list, but internal code can modify its contents - external can't. In second example both internal and external code can modify contents of the list, but only internal code can replace the list entirely.

Comment: I'm much more confused now. Doesn't private set mean modifying it's content only in that class?

Comment: `private set` means the instance the property points to can only be changed in that class. It has nothing to do with the content of the list. The second example publicly exposes the list as a MutableList rather than a read-only List, which means the content (which items are contained in the list) can be publicly modified.

Comment: `private set` is exactly the same as having `public List getItems()` and `private void setItems(List)`. You can't access `setItems()` method from outside of the object, but you can use `getItems()` and then use methods like `add()`, `remove()` or `clear()` on it to modify its contents (assuming it wasn't protected with e.g. `unmodifiableList()`).